# Standalone use of "vantage"

Tags: word-usage

We usually say "vantage point" and while the Webster's definition for the word vantage is a place or position affording a good view of something." the example is
"from my vantage point I could see into the front yard"

Can we ever use "vantage" as a standalone word?

Comment: I have read "vantage" to mean what I would interpret as "point of view" many times.

Comment: It is sometimes used to modify words other than _point_; one modern term of this sort is "[vantage time](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vantage+time%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1973%2Ccd_max%3A2019%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALiCzsawTHYGoH1li7l0xq3SzuJGVIuz4g%3A1652229183804&ei=PwR7YsTgMInTkPIPp5yAoAg&ved=0ahUKEwiE_Nmsmdb3AhWJKUQIHScOAIQQ4dUDCAg&oq=%22vantage+time%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAwyBQghEKsCMgUIIRCrAjIFCCEQqwI6BQgAEIAEULIKWMY6YL5JaABwAHgAgAF4iAGxB5IBAzMuNpgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books)." But you're asking about use of _vantage_ as a standalone noun, right?

Comment: It's extremely popular in commerce, developments etc: Aston Martin / legal firms / brokers .... It's hard to filter all these out and arrive at some internet examples of the use of the common noun. But it seems to be archaic outside of the given phrase (though Rosamund Moon doesn't include it as a _cranberry collocation_ in  her prestigious _Fixed Expressions and Idioms in English: A Corpus-based Approach._).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge this word isn't used outside of "vantage point" in today's English, but certainly it was once. It meant an advantage, or a superior position.

- John Foxe: "The Londoners seeing that they could get no vantage against the duke ... they took his arms, which in most despiteful wise they hanged up in the open places of the city in sign of reproach, as for a traitor; ..."
- Shakespeare: "O happy vantage of a kneeling knee!"

A vantage point is a place that gives you a good view, i.e. an advantageous one.